# Replace ASP.NET AJAX with jQuery for ASHX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been using the following to communicate with a Web Proxy for cross domain calls. I'm updating some code, and already use jQuery, and want to drop ASP AJAX because I only use it for this now.

Is it possible to do the following with jQuery only?

```
function download(proxyUrl, contentUrl, isJson, callback) {
    var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
    request.set_httpVerb("GET");

    var isCache = false;
    var url = proxyUrl + "?url=" + escape(contentUrl) + (isJson ? "&type=" + escape("application/json") : "") + "&cache=" + (isCache ? "10" : "0");
    request.set_url(url);

    request.add_completed(function (executor) {
        if (executor.get_responseAvailable()) {
            var content = executor.get_responseData();
            callback(content);
        }
    });

    var executor = new Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor();
    request.set_executor(executor);
    executor.executeRequest();
}
download("/_layouts/teamfusion/WebProxy.ashx", "http://www.twitter.com", false, function(content) {
    alert(content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    complete: callback
});
```

Here is the documentation for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).